# Mi algoritmo está contando una línea de más en cada fichero a analizar, y cuando el fichero solo tiene una línea, no la importa

Tags: php, symfony

Tengo el siguiente Command para importar los archivos de log de un servicio squid, desde un directorio xxx y y cuyos nombres contengan un substring con el formato de fecha especificado como argumento del command, hacia una base de datos, pero el mismo tiene 3 problemas: está contando una linea de más como posibles a analizar (importar),  segundo problema es que cuando el fichero tiene una sola línea de log, no la procesa porque cuenta 0 líneas reales a pesar de contar 2 líneas como posible, y tercero en algunos casos cuenta 2 líneas menos como procesadas más sin embargo procesa las reales existentes en el archivo.
Hablo de "posibles líneas" a importar y "líneas reales" porque se da el caso que algunos ficheros tienen una última línea en blanco y aunque establecí flags para que no las procesara, las está contando como posibles líneas a procesar.

Clase Command:

```
#[AsCommand(
        name: 'squidmgr:import:squid-log',
        description: 'Importa a la base de datos los archivos de log del Squid del directorio especificado cuyo nombre coincide con el formato especificado',
        aliases: ['squidmgr:import:squid-log'],
        hidden: false
)]
```

class ImportSQUIDLogsFilesCommand extends Command
{

```
use LockableTrait;

public function __construct(private readonly ManagerRegistry $manager, private readonly Filesystem $filesystem, private readonly string $squidLogsDir, private readonly string $dateFormatInLogFilename, private readonly LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    parent::__construct();
}

protected function configure(): void
{
    $this->addArgument('squidLogDir', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, "El directorio donde se almacenan los logs", $this->squidLogsDir);
    $this->addArgument('dateFormatInLogFilename', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, "El formato del fecha a buscar en nombres de los archivos de log", $this->dateFormatInLogFilename);
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    if (!$this->lock())
    {
        $output->writeln('<info>The command is already running in another process.</info>');

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }

    $em = $this->manager->getManager();
    $em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

    $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
    $io->title(sprintf("======= Importar registros de navegacion desde '%s' =======", $this->squidLogsDir));

    try {
        $logDir = $input->getArgument('squidLogDir');
        $dateFormatInLogFilename = $input->getArgument('dateFormatInLogFilename');
        $ficherosEnDirectorio = @scandir($logDir, \SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
        $ficheros = [];
        foreach ($ficherosEnDirectorio as $f)
        {
            $coincidencia = preg_match($dateFormatInLogFilename, $f) === 1 ? true : false;
            if ($coincidencia === true)
            {
                $ficheros[] = $f;
            }
        }
        $numOfFilesToProcess = count($ficheros);
        $output->writeln(sprintf("Archivos a procesar: '%s'", $numOfFilesToProcess));
        $output->writeln("");

        $processedFiles = 0;
        $output->writeln("");
        foreach ($ficheros as $filename)
        {
            $numOfLinesProcesseds = 0;
            $matches = [];
            $coincidencia = preg_match($dateFormatInLogFilename, $filename, $matches) === 1 ? true : false;
            if ($coincidencia === true)
            {
                $filePath = $this->squidLogsDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
                $io->section(sprintf("Importando archivo '%s'", $filename));

                /**
                 * Construir objeto fecha de los registros contenidos en el archivo a partir de
                 * la cadena de fecha encontrada en el nombre que incluye el formato Y-m-d
                 * * */
                $fechaStr = $matches[0];

                $fechaRegistros = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $fechaStr);

                if ((false !== $fechaRegistros) && ($fechaRegistros instanceof \DateTime) && (checkdate((int) $fechaRegistros->format('m'), (int) $fechaRegistros->format('d'), (int) $fechaRegistros->format('Y'))) === true)
                {
                    $accessLogObjExistente = $em->getRepository(AccessLog::class)->findOneBy(['fecha' => $fechaRegistros]);
                    if (!is_null($accessLogObjExistente))
                    {
                        goto NEXT_FILE;
                    } else
                    {
                        /**
                         * NOTA: Esta entidad representa el fichero de log de 1 día
                         * * */
                        $nuevoAccessLogObj = new AccessLog();

                        $nuevoAccessLogObj->setFecha($fechaRegistros);
                        $em->persist($nuevoAccessLogObj);
                        $em->flush();

                        $file = new \SplFileObject($filePath, "r");
                        $file->setFlags(
                                \SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD |                                    
                                \SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY |                                    
                                \SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE
                        );
                        $fileSize = $file->getSize();
                        if ($fileSize === 0)
                        {
                            goto NEXT_FILE;
                        }
                        $file->seek($fileSize);
                        $numOfLines = ($file->key() + 1);
                        $file->rewind();

                        $output->writeln("Posibles lineas a importar: " . $numOfLines);
                        $progressBar = new ProgressBar($output, $numOfLines);
                        $progressBar->start();
                        try {
                            $i = 0;
                            $batchSize = 100;
                            while (!$file->eof())
                            {
                                $currentLine = $file->fgets();
                                /**
                                 * NOTA: El objeto devuelto por el parser representa una linea dentro del fichero de log de 1 dia.
                                 * * */
                                $accessLogRegistro = SQUIDLogLineParser::parseLine($currentLine);
                                if ($accessLogRegistro instanceof AccessLogRegistro)
                                {
                                    $accessLogRegistro->setAccessLog($nuevoAccessLogObj);
                                    $em->persist($accessLogRegistro);
                                    ++$i;
                                    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0)
                                    {
                                        $em->flush();
                                        $em->clear();

                                        $nuevoAccessLogObj = $em->getReference(AccessLog::class, $nuevoAccessLogObj->getId());
                                    }

                                    $numOfLinesProcesseds += 1;
                                    $progressBar->advance();
                                }
                            }
                            $em->flush();
                            $em->clear();
                        } catch (\Exception $exc) {

                            throw $exc;
                        }
                        $progressBar->finish();
                        $file = null;

                        $nuevoAccessLogObj = $em->getRepository(AccessLog::class)->find($nuevoAccessLogObj->getId());
                        if ($numOfLinesProcesseds > 0)
                        {
                            $nuevoAccessLogObj->setNumeroDeFilasProcesadas($numOfLinesProcesseds);
                            $em->flush();
                        } else
                        {
                            $em->remove($nuevoAccessLogObj);
                            $em->flush();
                        }

                        $processedFiles += 1;
                    }
                } else
                {
                    $output->writeln("");
                    $output->writeln(sprintf("El fichero '%s' ya ha sido importado con anterioridad", $filename));
                }

                NEXT_FILE:
            }
            $output->writeln("");
            $output->writeln(sprintf("Fueron procesadas '%s' lineas del fichero '%s'", $numOfLinesProcesseds, $filename));
        }
    } catch (IOException $ioExc) {
        $this->logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", self::class, __FUNCTION__, $ioExc->getMessage()));
        $output->writeln(sprintf("<error>%s</error>", $ioExc->getMessage()));
        return Command::FAILURE;
    } catch (\RuntimeException $rtExc) {
        $this->logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", self::class, __FUNCTION__, $rtExc->getMessage()));
        $output->writeln(sprintf("<error>%s</error>", $rtExc->getMessage()));
        return Command::FAILURE;
    } catch (\Exception $exc) {
        throw $exc;
        $this->logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", self::class, __FUNCTION__, $exc->getTraceAsString()));
        $output->writeln(sprintf("<error>%s</error>", $exc->getTraceAsString()));
        return Command::FAILURE;
    }

    $output->writeln(sprintf("<info>Fueron procesados '%s' archivos de log.</info>", $processedFiles));

    $this->release();
    return Command::SUCCESS;
}
```

}

Esta es la salida durante el procesamiento del command:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- La selección en rojo representa el caso de un archivo que contiene
  una sola lína de log y una en blanco al final. (no procesa la línea
  de log).
- La selección azul representa el caso de un archivo en el que da como
  posibles líneas a procesar una de más (la última en blanco, pero sí
  procesa las reales).
- La selección en verde representa el caso de un archivo que contiene
  una línea en blanco al final (la da dentro de la cuenta de las
  posibles a procesar), informa que procesó una de menos de las reales,
  pero realmente sí se importaron las líneas reales de logs.

**Actualización**:
He cambiado el orden de las flags del objeto SplFileObject sin conseguir resultado. Revisando las líneas importadas de cada fichero en la base de datos puedo apreciar que efectivamente no se importa la primera línea de ningún fichero, es por eso que un archivo a importar que tenga una línea de log no se importa. Influyendo además en la diferencia entre posibles líneas a importar y líneas realmente importadas a la base de datos (no se importa la línea 1 de ningún fichero, y por supuesto no se importa ninguna línea vacía)
Una vez hecho `$file->rewind()` se supone que el cursor se posicione en la línea 0 del archivo.

**Actualización 2:**
El asunto está en que `fgets()` obtiene la siguiente línea a partir de la posición actual, y al ubicar el "cursor" en la primera línea, evidentemente `fgets()` se la salta.

Comment: Ponle un ```else``` al ```if $accessLogRegistro instanceof AccessLogRegistro``` y cuenta cuantas líneas van por ese lado, es decir, que el parse no devolvió una instancia. Al menos, si ninguna se va por este ```else``` ya es un buen problema.

Comment: el manual de php dice: **SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY** Saltar líneas vacías en el fichero. Esto requiere que la bandera **READ_AHEAD** esté activada para que funcione como se tenía previsto. y como yo lo veo no esta correcto, prueba ordenar las flags en el orden correcto, `\SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD | \SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | \SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE`

Comment: @John he cambiado el orden de las banderas, y se mantiene el problema. Revisando los registros importados en la base de datos, efectivamente la primera línea de cada fichero no se está importando.

Comment: Disculpa que te pueda responder hasta ahora pero los administradores del sitio te banean por ayudar , mira ordena las flags asi:
`$file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD); $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY); $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);` 
espero funcione, si ya lo solucionaste danos tu solucion.

Comment: @John realmente eliminé del algoritmo el conteo de líneas, teniendo en cuenta que el command se ejecutará mediante cron, y a no ser que sea necesario ejecutar la tarea "manualmente desde el terminal", no es necesario tantos mensajes en el $output. Por ese motivo no he redactado la respuesta final, teniendo en cuenta el cambio en el código. De todos modos quedé con la duda y por eso escribí la Actualización 2, probaré establecer las flags por separado como me comentas y cualquier resultado le cuento.